# Divide a dataset into multiple small datasets and writing it into csv files using R

Tags: r, loops, csv, dataset

I am a beginner to R and I want help for a task,

I have imported a large csv file (around 20 columns and ~40000 rows) in R

```
ParentAccount <- read.csv("FullAccountList.csv")
```

I want to break this ParentAccount dataset (row-wise) into multiple small datasets with approximately 2000 rows each and write it to those many CSV files. (In this case there could around 20 CSV files).

I can do it with long approach by dividing the dataset and writing write.csv statement multiple times but I am looking towards a more optimized way...

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I don't want to divide into multiple datasets by randomly selecting the rows. I want to maintain the sequence of rows. Example, row 1 to 2000 in first dataset, 2001 to 4000 in second and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using the `iris` data set.

```
ParentAccount <- iris
# split you data in a list of 5 dataframes, each has 30 rows
# In your case, it's a list of 20 dataframes, each has 2000 rows
ParentAccount.ls <- split(ParentAccount, rep(1:5, each = 30)) # in your case, use rep(1:20, each = 2000)
# save the files
lapply(names(ParentAccount.ls),
       function(x) {write.csv(ParentAccount.ls[[x]],
                              file = paste("FullAccountList", x, ".csv", sep = ""))})
```